# In which cases can I reuse a django project for multiple applications?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I just finished doing the tutorial django app. I now want to build my own app. Should I just create a new app within the tutorial project folder or should I create a new project folder with a new app?

I am unsure in which cases it makes sense to re-use a project and create multiple apps under that project vs. making new projects for each new app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A website is usually a project. In that website, you may have multiple features (a blog, a wiki, etc.). Each of those features should be an application in the project.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a project for each app.  When you create a project, you can define new apps inside a project if you want, in fact the `manage.py` inside the project folder is the same as the `django-admin.py` outside.  So you can `startapp` directly using `django-admin.py`:

```
$ django-admin.py startproject foo
$ django-admin.py startapp bar
$ ls foo bar/
bar/:
__init__.py  models.py  tests.py  views.py

foo:
__init__.py  manage.py  settings.py  urls.py
```